# What is the best way to store/read multiple user settings in a C# Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, .net

The title pretty much says it all. I've been searching and I haven't really found a good way to deal with settings/configurations for multiple users.

The best I found was a loosely worded thing about using AppData, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach; I'd like my application to be used by many, and plenty of people don't use multiple profiles on a computer.

Comment: I initially thought you were talking about accessing other users profiles, but you're actually talking about the opposite, aren't you? (Allowing multiple separate sets of settings to coexist within a single profile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating xml document for each user from where you'll read/write settings for each user?
If you use database, create a new table called settings, and then name all the fields with the settings you have. Populate the table with true/false values and the user id. 
Maybe that can help.

Comment: Do you have any information/links with information on how to create an xml document for each user?  That sounds great.

Comment: check this example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/readwritexmltutmellli2111282005041517am/readwritexmltutmellli21.aspx

Comment: +1 for the database part! it's more synchronous that way if the user used different PC would still have the same settings

Answer (score 0):

The best way would surely be with a new User Settings profile.

Click add new item then select Settings.

You can then call these with something like this:

```
string temp_setting = setting_name.Default.item_name;
```

Where setting_name is the name of the new settings file you've created and the item_name is the name of the property within the settings.